# Using Named Credentials Instead Custom Settings

Tags: namedcredentials

For integration with Box I have process where I make callout to Box and get token in return.

Currently the settings are stored in metadata and I'm checking if I can use instead Named Credentials.
But I'm note sure if/how I can store the box clientId/cliecntSecret in the named credentials and then send it in the body of he request.

The current relevant code is:

```
httpRequest req = new httpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndPoint('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setBody('client_id=' + boxAppSettings.ClientId__c + 
            '&client_secret=' + boxAppSettings.Client_Secret__c + 
            '&grant_type=client_credentials'+ 
            '&box_subject_type=enterprise&box_subject_id=' + boxAppSettings.Enterprise_Id__c);
```

I think that technically I can set Named Credentials based on username/password and store there the box client/secret and then use below, but it doesn't seems like the right approach.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
req.setBody('client_id=' + '{!$Credential.UserName}' + 
                '&client_secret=' + '{!$Credential.Password}' + 
                '&grant_type=client_credentials'+ 
                '&box_subject_type=enterprise&box_subject_id=' + boxAppSettings.Enterprise_Id__c);
```

Comment: @identigral thanks, but it is not. The other post uses password/username and it is good to use the '{!Credentials.Password} merge field in such case. I need to use client secret/client id in the body request, and I'm not sure where to store them in the named credentials.

Comment: Client ID = username, Client Secret = password

Comment: I can use this approach clientId/secret as username/password, it is what I wrote in the second code example, just wasn't sure it is the right approach. thanks.